# Explode random unpredictagle tags in an array

Tags: php, arrays, dom, innerhtml

Below is some random unpredictable set of tags wrapped inside a div tag. How to explode all the child tags innerHTML preserving the order of its occurrence.

Note: In case of img, iframe tags need to extract only the urls.

```
 <div>
  <p>para-1</p>
  <p>para-2</p>
  <p>
    text-before-image
    <img src="text-image-src"/>
    text-after-image</p>
  <p>
    <iframe src="p-iframe-url"></iframe>
  </p>
  <iframe src="iframe-url"></iframe>
  <h1>header-1</h1>
  <img src="image-url"/>
  <p>
    <img src="p-image-url"/>
  </p>
  content not wrapped within any tags
  <h2>header-2</h2>
  <p>para-3</p>
  <ul>
    <li>list-item-1</li>
    <li>list-item-2</li>
  </ul>
  <span>span-content</span>
 content not wrapped within any tags
</div>
```

**Expected array:**

```
 ["para-1","para-2","text-before-image","text-image-src","text-after-image",
"p-iframe-url","iframe-url","header-1","image-url",
"p-image-url","content not wrapped within any tags","header-2","para-3",
"list-item-1","list-item-2","span-content","content not wrapped within any tags"]
```

**Relevant code:**

```
 $dom     = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML( $content );
        $tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'p' );
        // Get all the paragraph tags, to iterate its nodes.
        $j = 0;
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
            // get_inner_html() to preserve the node's text & tags
            $con[ $j ] = $this->get_inner_html( $tag );
            // Check if the Node has html content or not
            if ( $con[ $j ] != strip_tags( $con[ $j ] ) ) {      
                // Check if the node contains html along with plain text with out any tags
                if ( $tag->nodeValue != '' ) {
                    /*
                     * DOM to get the Image SRC of a node
                     */
                    $domM      = new DOMDocument();
                    /*
                     * Setting encoding type http://in1.php.net/domdocument.loadhtml#74777
                     * Set after initilizing DomDocument();
                     */
                    $con[ $j ] = mb_convert_encoding( $con[ $j ], 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8" );
                    @$domM->loadHTML( $con[ $j ] );
                    $y = new DOMXPath( $domM );
                    foreach ( $y->query( "//img" ) as $node ) {
                        $con[ $j ] = "img=" . $node->getAttribute( "src" );
                        // Increment the Array size to accomodate bad text and image tags.
                        $j++;
                        // Node incremented, fetch the node value and accomodate the text without any tags.
                        $con[ $j ] = $tag->nodeValue;
                    }
                    $domC      = new DOMDocument();
                    @$domC->loadHTML( $con[ $j ] );
                    $z = new DOMXPath( $domC );
                    foreach ( $z->query( "//iframe" ) as $node ) {
                        $con[ $j ] = "vid=http:" . $node->getAttribute( "src" );
                        // Increment the Array size to accomodate bad text and image tags.

                        $j++;
                        // Node incremented, fetch the node value and accomodate the text without any tags.
                        $con[ $j ] = $tag->nodeValue;
                    }
                } else {
                    /*
                     * DOM to get the Image SRC of a node
                     */
                    $domA      = new DOMDocument();
                    @$domA->loadHTML( $con[ $j ] );
                    $x = new DOMXPath( $domA );
                    foreach ( $x->query( "//img" ) as $node ) {
                        $con[ $j ] = "img=" . $node->getAttribute( "src" );
                    }

                    if ( $con[ $j ] != strip_tags( $con[ $j ] ) ) {
                        foreach ( $x->query( "//iframe" ) as $node ) {
                            $con[ $j ] = "vid=http:" . $node->getAttribute( "src" );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // INcrement the node
            $j++;
        }

        $this->content = $con;
```

Comment: @jeroen Using dom api, succeeded in extracting only <p> tags innerhtml preserving its occurrences. But failed when other than p tags existed.

Comment: why not just `strip_tags()`? that'll yank out all the containing html and leave just the text, and do it in the order the html/text appears in the file.

Comment: @MarcB What will happen to the iframe & image paths if just strip_tags()

Comment: You are not wanting to get the "innerHTML". You want to look at retrieving values of "attributes" (e.g. the iframe src) as well as the "text content" of elements. Those keywords should get you going.

Comment: If you showed us relevant parts of your code, we would get a better idea on which approach you chose, and might even spot bugs if your not up against a conceptual error (only).

Comment: @LeventePánczél posted relevant parts of my code. and yes thanks for pointing out `<p> sometext1 <img href="ref" /> sometext2 <p>`

Comment: Your code is much more complicated, than it has to be. For example, when you loaded the document, you will not need to call loadHTML() again for its sub-parts, because they are already there as a tree of DOMNode objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and easy way of extracting interesting pieces of information from a DOM document is to make use of XPath.   Below is a basic example showing how to get the text content and attribute text from a div element.

```
<?php

// Pre-amble, scroll down to interesting stuff...
$html = '<div>
  <p>para-1</p>
  <p>para-2</p>
  <p>
    <iframe src="p-iframe-url"></iframe>
  </p>
  <iframe src="iframe-url"></iframe>
  <h1>header-1</h1>
  <img src="image-url"/>
  <p>
    <img src="p-image-url"/>
  </p>
  content not wrapped within any tags
  <h2>header-2</h2>
  <p>para-3</p>
  <ul>
    <li>list-item-1</li>
    <li>list-item-2</li>
  </ul>
  <span>span-content</span>
 content not wrapped within any tags
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$div = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);

// Interesting stuff:

// Use XPath to get all text nodes and attribute text
// $tests becomes a DOMNodeList filled with DOMText and DOMAttr objects
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$texts = $xpath->query('descendant-or-self::*/text()|descendant::*/@*', $div);

// You could only include/exclude specific attributes by looking at their name
// e.g. multiple paths: .//@src|.//@href
// or whitelist:        descendant::*/@*[name()="src" or name()="href"]
// or blacklist:        descendant::*/@*[not(name()="ignore")]

// Build an array of the text held by the DOMText and DOMAttr objects
// skipping any boring whitespace
$results = array();
foreach ($texts as $text) {
    $trimmed_text = trim($text->nodeValue);
    if ($trimmed_text !== '') {
        $results[] = $trimmed_text;
    }
}

// Let's see what we have
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The snippet works perfectly fine. But, the array is built with unwanted DOMAttr objects(style, height, width, alt, rel,..). How to discard it?

Comment: Change the XPath expression to only match the attributes that you are interested in. This could involve changing the `@*` part, or adding a predicate (a filter) to whitelist or blacklist attribute names. That's entirely up to you.

Comment: Thanks very much @salathe, XPath expression `$texts = $xpath->query('descendant-or-self::*/text()|descendant::*/@*[name()="src" or name()="href"]', $div);` worked out. Now, say If I have to blacklist a p tag with class **remove** `<p class="remove">Dont show me</p>`. How do I filter it? thanks...

Comment: Exceptions should be filtered in the foreach($texts) loop. If $text->nodeType and/or $text->nodeName and/or other properties of $text are identifying the node as "bad", don't add it to the results.

Comment: You could filter out that element by matching elements that aren't paragraphs with that class... e.g. `descendant-or-self::*[not(self::p[@class="remove"])]` -- it looks like you should be spending some time over the weekend reading up on XPath. A good intro is [Tobias Schlitt's XPath overview](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html).

Comment: Thanks.. @salathe `descendant-or-self::*[not(self::p[@class="remove"])]` isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Isn't working" isn't much help. I'm also sorry to say it but this is not a support forum for us (me) to work through your code with you… there are plenty other suitable places for that (forums, IRC, mailing lists, and so on).

Comment: @LeventePánczél LocationPath `descendant-or-self::text()` does not help me predict nodeName ul, p or span in the foreach($texts). They all return "#text". Any idea or resources which will help me predict the tags the nodeValue were wrapped in...?

Comment: @salathe Thanks for your help, the desired LocationPath is `'descendant-or-self::*//*[not(self::style|self::span|self::ul|self::p[@class="remove"])]|descendant::*/@*[name()="src" or name()="href"]'`

Answer (score 1):

Try a recursive approach! Get an empty array `$parts` on your class instance and a function `extractSomething(DOMNode $source)`. You function should the process each separate case, and then return. If source is a

- TextNode: push to $parts
- Element and name=img: push its href to $parts
- other special cases
- Element: for each TextNode or Element child call extractSomething(child)

Now when a call to extractSomenting(yourRootDiv) returns, you will have the list in $this->parts.

Note that you have not defined what happens with `<p> sometext1 <img href="ref" /> sometext2 <p>` but the above example is driving toward adding 3 elements ("sometext1", "ref" and "sometext2") on its behalf.

This is just a rough outline of the solution. The point is that you need to process each node in the tree (possibly not really regarding its position), and while walking them in the right order, you build your array by transforming each node to the desired text. Recursion is the fastest to code but you may alternatively try width traversal or walker tools.

Bottom line is that you have to accomplish two tasks: walk the nodes in a correct order, transform each to the desired result.

This is basically a rule of thumb for processing a tree/graph structure.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to use DOMDocument:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

Comment: succeeded in extracting only <p> tags innerhtml preserving its occurrences. But failed when other than p tags existed.

Comment: Please add some kind of explanation on how the op could use DOMDocument, perhaps with some example.